# What is the code doing in a Python queue "peek"?

Tags: python, stack, queue

This python code below uses a queue system with two stacks. From what I understand, during the "peek" function--we are looking at the top of the list and returning it.

```
def peek(self):
    #looks at the top of the queue
    if len(self.stack2) > 0:
        top = self.stack2.pop() 
        self.stack2.append(top)
    else:
        #takes items in stack 1 and put into stack 2
        while len(self.stack1) > 1:
            self.stack2.append(self.stack1.pop())
        top = self.stack1.pop() 
        self.stack2.append(top) 
    return top
```

As you can see in the first if statement condition, it does a `self.stack2.pop()` and appends it to `top`. However the `.pop()` method is supposed to remove the item at the end of the list. Why is it being assigned to `top`? Shouldn't we use `self.stack2.pop(0)` which would remove the first item in the queue?

Comment: `stack2` is not a list, it's a stack (conceptually, anyway). A stack has only two operations: push and pop. They both operate on the "top" of the stack. Therefore `push(pop())` is a no-op (assuming no underflow).

Comment: I'm sorry...but isn't python .pop() method just removing items at end of queue/list? How does it suddenly start removing it at the beginning?

Comment: It removes from the end, and append adds to the end. The end of the list is the "top"of the stack.

Comment: Actually...one last question....in queues...don't we "pop" it off from the front BUT append it to the end? So you are saying it is popping off the front of the queue and adding it back to the front of the queue? That doesn't change anything though

Comment: Yes, the top of the stack is the front of the queue, that's how this implementation of a queue works